# Overriding @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I'm developing a Spring Integration/Boot application. I'm using a multi-document `application.yml` (src/main/resources/application.yml) to set defaults for several configuration classes (annotated with @ConfigurationProperties). Applicaiton.yml comes with defaults, and some of them need to be overridden, depending on the environment.

I'm open to either using Java system properties (-D...=...), Spring "properties" (--...=...), or preferably a yaml file located outside a Jar, in a directory.

Application.yml has 4 documents and each one corresponds to a different configuration class. Let's just focus on ServerConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(locations = "classpath:application.yml", prefix = "server")
public class ServerConfig {
    private Integer port;
    private String address;

    public Integer getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public void setPort(Integer port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

Application.yml:

```
server:
  address: ::1
  port: 8080

---
```

Notice how I have `locations` specified in the annotation. This loads application.yml and uses those values successfully, but I can't figure out how to override them (say -Dserver.port=7777 or --server.port=7777). If I remove `locations = ...`, then I can use `-Dserver.port=7777, but the defaults in application.yml are never loaded, so I have to specify every single value as a command line argument.

I've read through https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html numerous times, and I can't understand why I can't leave `locations = 'application.yml'` in the config annotations and selectively override with system properties.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: why do you want to replace the built-in server properties with a class of your own? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerProperties.java maybe it's clashing

Comment: @zapl: I didn't even know that exists, but I don't think it's applicable to Spring Integration or outside a servlet. Anyways, I have 3 config classes for application-specific configuration that run into this exact same problem. This one was just the simplest for people to understand.

Comment: Oops true, that's only part of spring-boot-web. Could it be https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5111 ? In other words `location` shouldn't be used but it's supposed to work without it.

Comment: I was reading through that same thread. That `locations` behavior is surprising, and honestly, terrible design. That being said, if I don't specify a location, nothing is loaded and eventually my code hits exceptions since config getters are returning null. I'm working on `application.yaml` using spring profiles and switching to using yaml documents per profile. Unfortunately, spring refuses to load `application.yaml` unless I put it in `locations`. I've followed through two tutorials, and I can't figure out why spring loads their application.yaml but won't touch mine.

Comment: maybe.. the config property bean is a `@Component` not a configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sigh*. It was a problem with application startup -- caused by confusion on my part between Spring Integration and Spring Boot.

My Main method used to be:

```
 @SpringBootApplication
 public class Main {
     public static void main(String... args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("org.fandingo.blah.blah");
        ctx.registerShutdownHook();
 }
```

My understanding is that's how you'd start an application that is Spring Integration only (assuming JavaConfig of course). The problem is that the YAML properties loading is a Spring Boot feature. Switching out the main method to use Spring Boot method fixed the issue:

```
 @SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Main.class);
        app.setRegisterShutdownHook(true);
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

Spring is so goddamned complex and cryptic. Why Spring Integration and Boot can't naturally cooperate is beyond me.